# Parsing JSON file swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am trying to display in a tableView the data gathered from a json file that looks like: https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/1000266/to/1000013

I want to display just the summary and description of each journey. I tried something like:

```
               do{
let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
                print(fetchedData.value(forKey: "journey"))

                if let journeyArray = fetchedData.value(forKey: "journey") as? NSArray{
                    for journey in journeyArray{
                        if let journeyDict = journey as? NSDictionary {
                            if let summary = journeyDict.value(forKey: "summary"){
                                self.summaryArray.append(summary as! String)
                            }
                            if let desc = journeyDict.value(forKey: "description"){
                                self.descArray.append(desc as! String)
                            }

                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                                self.journeysTableView.reloadData()
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                self.journeysTableView.reloadData()
            }
```

and

```
 do{
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                print(fetchedData)

                for eachFetchedJourney in fetchedData{
                    let eachJourney = eachFetchedJourney as! [String: Any]
                    let summary = eachJourney["summary"] as! String
                    let description = eachJourney["description"] as! String

                    self.fetchedJourneys.append(Journey(summary: summary, description: description))
                    print(fetchedData)
                }
                self.journeysTableView.reloadData()
            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
```

but I still can't get the parsing right. Would be anyone able to help me?

Comment: use http://www.json4swift.com/

Comment: Provide JSON sample to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First please check your response in JSON viewer 
[Here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Then check your dictionary you are directly using Key 'summary' from your Array 'journeyArray', Where you can find your 'summary' key is in your 'legs' Array -> 'instruction' dictionary.

So Do It Accordingly.

The best way is Use https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper which automatically converts JSON your response data.